# iframes rendering mysteriously differently from regular web pages?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, dom, browser

I'm having an issue where iframes are rendering differenty from pages outside iframes. This is happening in Chrome and Firefox. What I really need to do is force the iframe to render in the same way as the regular main page.  I am in a situation where I cannot change the content inside the iframe.

Two examples:

**Example 1: Margins above H1s**

Code (this is the entire HTML file):

```
<h1>hello</h1>

<br><br>

<iframe srcdoc="<h1>hello</h1>"></iframe>
```

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot 1]

Problem:

There is too much margin above the H1 in the iframe. I need to make them match. And specifically, I need the h1 inside the iframe to match. And, this can't be a specific CSS hack for this specific situation. I know that here I could modify the iframe code to hack it with CSS. But why is it rendering differently?

**Example 2: Missing specification of 'px' in css**

Code (this is the entire HTML file):

```
<div style='border:1px solid black;width:30px;height:30px;border-radius:30'></div>

<br><br>

<iframe srcdoc="<div style='border:1px solid black;width:30px;height:30px;border-radius:30'></div>"></iframe>
```

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot 2]

Problem:

In the iframe, the border-radius parameter is ignored, because there is a missing 'px'.  Outside the iframe it is fine. Again, obviously I can add 'px' inside the iframe, but unfortunately here that is not an option. How can I make the iframe render the same way as the main page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parent document is rendered using a different parser (I guess Quirks mode) from the iframe. As the `srcdoc` attribute is a html5 only attribute the iframe is rendered using the html5 parser.

If you define the parent document as html5 by adding `<!DOCTYPE html>`, you'll notice that the parent document will also have the additional margin and the square.

Perhaps you can try adding another doctype to the `srcdoc` string to force the browser to render it in another mode. I couldn't get that to work, and I guess it's not supported.

Comment: This is indeed a Quirks Mode issue, but it is not a parser issue and it does not depend on the `srcdoc` attribute. *Any* doctype that conforms to published HTML specifications will trigger “standards mode”; `<!DOCTYPE html>` is just the simplest way to achieve this. So this is not an HTML5 issue; the difference between Quirks Mode and “standard mode” predates HTML5 by many years.

Comment: According to the HTML5 Recommendation, any document created with the `srcdoc` attribute is rendered in “no-quirks mode” (their word for “standard mode”). This is a bit hidden there, but it’s said at http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#the-initial-insertion-mode

Comment: Great, yeah, this is it. Special thanks to Jukka - you found that in the docs. Awesome.

Comment: As @JukkaK.Korpela said, any document created with the `srcdoc` attribute is rendered in "no-quirks mode." But note specifically that "no-quirks mode" is used even if the document specifies a quirky DOCTYPE. That is implied in the specification, but spelled our more clearly here https://github.com/w3c/html/issues/254